# Active(anon) + Inactive(anon) is more than AnonPages

Tags: linux, memory

```
$ grep -iE 'anon' /proc/meminfo
Active(anon):    2962828 kB
Inactive(anon):  1039836 kB
AnonPages:       2599436 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
```

Q1. Assuming there are zero "huge pages", do you know why there would be a difference between Active(anon) + Inactive(anon) and AnonPages?

Q2. What is the best overall summary of anonymous memory?

I looked at [man proc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html), but it does not tell me very much:

> Active(anon) %lu (since Linux 2.6.28) [To be documented.]
>
> Inactive(anon) %lu (since Linux 2.6.28) [To be documented.]
>
> [...]
>
> AnonPages %lu (since Linux 2.6.18):
>
> Non-file backed pages mapped into user-space page tables.

---

```
$ uname -r  # My kernel version
5.0.17-200.fc29.x86_64
```

I see the same dichotomy in zoneinfo:

```
$ getconf PAGESIZE
4096

$ grep -C0 -i anon /proc/zoneinfo
      nr_inactive_anon 261105
      nr_active_anon 742227
--
      nr_isolated_anon 0
--
      nr_anon_pages 651405
--
      nr_anon_transparent_hugepages 0
--
      nr_zone_inactive_anon 0
      nr_zone_active_anon 0
--
      nr_zone_inactive_anon 59018
      nr_zone_active_anon 329082
--
      nr_zone_inactive_anon 202087
      nr_zone_active_anon 413145
```

```
$ grep -C0 -E "Node|zone[^_]" /proc/zoneinfo
Node 0, zone      DMA
--
Node 0, zone    DMA32
--
Node 0, zone   Normal
--
Node 0, zone  Movable
--
Node 0, zone   Device
```

```
$ cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:        8042664 kB
MemFree:         1697716 kB
MemAvailable:    3108172 kB
Buffers:          186476 kB
Cached:          3046440 kB
SwapCached:        14580 kB
Active:          3830020 kB
Inactive:        1738252 kB
Active(anon):    2965992 kB
Inactive(anon):  1044420 kB
Active(file):     864028 kB
Inactive(file):   693832 kB
Unevictable:      276372 kB
Mlocked:           13560 kB
SwapTotal:       2097148 kB
SwapFree:        1465040 kB
Dirty:              7376 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       2602632 kB
Mapped:           696488 kB
Shmem:           1670792 kB
KReclaimable:     164272 kB
Slab:             327948 kB
SReclaimable:     164272 kB
SUnreclaim:       163676 kB
KernelStack:       21408 kB
PageTables:        42976 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     6118480 kB
Committed_AS:   14143048 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
Percpu:             3424 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
CmaTotal:              0 kB
CmaFree:               0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
Hugetlb:               0 kB
DirectMap4k:      492084 kB
DirectMap2M:     7774208 kB
DirectMap1G:     1048576 kB
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Files created in a `tmpfs` are counted in `Active(anon) + Inactive(anon)` (and in `Shmem`), but not in `AnonPages`.  (Unless the file data is paged out to a swap device).

This is explained in [Redhat documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/s2-proc-meminfo), and it can be verified in a simple test.  So it is not surprising to see some difference.

We can see that is not quite the complete explanation...

- `Active(anon):    2965992 kB`
- `Inactive(anon):  1044420 kB`
- `AnonPages:       2602632 kB`
- `Shmem:           1670792 kB`

I expect the difference between `Active(anon) + Inactive(anon)` and `AnonPages + Shmem` is explained by:

- `Unevictable:      276372 kB`

This raises a second question :-). [Why is "Unevictable" memory larger than "Mlocked" memory?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/525114/why-is-unevictable-memory-larger-than-mlocked-memory)

- `Mlocked:           13560 kB`